# Short fiction where America is at war with Canada

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alternate-history

I'm looking for an short-fiction alternate-history book collection where different groups are at war with each other for different reasons. It was probably made during the 1980s or 1990s.

In one of them there's an alternate history where Islam, Iran, and so forth are not religious enemies but are united in a federation. America is the third world country divided and hopelessly backwards, at war with Canada, burns maple trees, maple syrup is on the black market. It's told from the perspective of a woman soldier who goes to America with war relief, is shot down out of the sky I think, and the head of their ambassador is sent home in a box after being cut off by American soldiers. Just because the they wanted them to stop fighting.

At the end of the book the woman hopes that the long war will eventually end someday.

What is the name of this story? Who is the Author? What collection does it come from?

Comment: Just reading that first sentence, was the collection holiday-themed? When did you read it? Where? Do you mean "third world" in terms of level of resources? In terms of whether they're not allied with either Capitalist or Communist forces? Do you remember approximately what time period the alternate history was set, level of technology, etc?

Comment: Just as it's said in the title. It was a collection of short stories, 9-13 stories. It was called Isaac Asimov Mother's day. The next one in the series was Isaac Asimov Moon. And so on. there are like ten books, all collected from Isaac Asimov Science fiction Magazine. 1993-1999

Comment: Ah. I really did not glean that from the sentence. I've modified it to make it more clear that you're talking about book titles.